# How can I add/remove music from my Ipod on Banshee?

Tags: banshee, ipod

I have a 8gb 4th generation Nano that I would like to begin using with Banshee. It's currently full and I need to delete some music on it. Is it possible to remove songs and add new ones using Banshee or do I need to use Rhythmbox or gtkpod?

Comment: I vote to reopen this question because of it is a different problem. Banshee seems to be able to gain access to the device, it means it is "visible" to banshee, but there is no visible option to easily add or remove songs on it. Ubuntu 12.04 - Banshee 2.4.1

Answer (score 2):

YMMV but I have been able to access my iPod classic in Banshee without any efforts. You will need to enable Apple Device Support. On attaching iPod, I can see it as a device and can add/ remove music.

Comment: The ipod is visible, but when i right click on a song in it's library I'm unable to delete it. When I try to drag a song from my banshee library into my ipod nothing happens.

Comment: i have the same problem!